# Turn a select into an an array for a DELETE FROM

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a sightly complex select that returns an array of id's. I'd now like to use this array of id

```
DELETE FROM cart_items WHERE id in (

    SELECT id AS the_count 
    FROM cart_items 
    GROUP BY session_code 
    HAVING COUNT(session_code) > 100

);
```

What i'd like to do is use the inside select (which works) as and array for the IN delete from...

This code is throwing the error:

"You can't specify target table 'cart_items' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: That should work as posted.

Comment: That's what I thought but it's not. I've added the error in it's throwing.

Comment: are you sure you want to group by session_code only, you will miss some id's this way. Look my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with a subselect and provide new alias

```
DELETE FROM cart_items WHERE id in (
SELECT cart_items_todelete.id FROM (
    SELECT id  
    FROM cart_items 
    GROUP BY session_code 
    HAVING COUNT(session_code) > 100 
) cart_items_todelete  

);
```

Comment: The odd thing is, this doesn't actually delete those records... they're still left behind when it's ran. Even though it says "14 records affected"

Comment: Then recheck the select query first then with subselect if you are getting desired ids Edit above query is nothing different it is just mapping to new alias from your original query you have to look at you original select and there will not filtering or other effect with the use of subslecet it is just mapping the rows

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder if you should not use a query like this instead ?

```
DELETE FROM cart_items WHERE id IN (
    SELECT c.id FROM (
        SELECT  a.id AS id FROM
            cart_items a, (
                SELECT session_code
                FROM cart_items
                GROUP BY session_code
                HAVING COUNT(session_code) > 100
        ) b
        WHERE
            a.session_code = b.session_code
    ) c
);
```

Your query and the suggested once in the answers here doesnt take in count that ID might differ. It is not always same ID for same session, right!

You will

- first find the session codes that appears more than 100 times
- find `all` id's that have this session code
- and finally delete those rows

Hope this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the EXISTS clause:

```
DELETE
  FROM cart_items TGT
 WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT 'x'
         FROM cart_items SRC
        WHERE SRC.session_code = TGT.session_code
        GROUP BY session_code
       HAVING COUNT(session_code) > 100
      );
```